# checking jquery slideup status?

Tags: jquery

I'm just curious if I should check the current status of my div tag before I call the slideup method. Here is what I'm currently calling:

```
        if(parseInt(msg.status)==1) {
            window.location=msg.txt;
        }
        else if(parseInt(msg.status)==0) {

            // Is it an issue that by default I first call the slideup method
            // regardless of it's state?
            $('#notify').slideUp('fast', function() {
                $('#notify').html(msg.txt).slideDown();
            });
        }
```

Everything works fine, but I was just curious if this is "bad" practice or not.

Comment: IMHO.. Its certainly could be made more efficient to check state before running the animation. But under the current circumstance I don't see that being an issue.

Comment: `slideUp` is checking visibility for you, so why bother doing so twice?

Comment: I'm basically trying to reset the status message in my div so sliding it up allows me to notify the user that something has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not needed, but if that code can run very frequently (like every half/second or basically faster than 'fast', or if it happens when a user hovers over something) then you could see the animations getting queued and running one after another, so you might want to add a `.stop(true,true).` before the slideup